# How to use variable from post method express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new in javascript and express js, I'm trying to post user current location from my leaflet map and use the current location as a query parameter to get restaurant nearby. Here is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db');
const landmark = db.get('landmark');
const request = db.get('request');
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = req.body;
    const location = {
      latitude,
      longitude
    };
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const latitude = location.latitude;
  const longitude = location.longitude;
  landmark
  .find(
    {
    geometry:{
        $nearSphere: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Point",
          coordinates : [longitude, latitude]
        },
        $minDistance: 0,
        $maxDistance: 500
        }}
  }
  )
  .then(landmark => {
    res.json(landmark);
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I want to use latitude longitude variable that I get from post method and place it into the coordinates in the query section in a get method. I keep getting error "longitude is not defined" or "latitude is not define" can anyone help me please?

Comment: You simply need to send a longitude and a latitude from a client to GET route

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask the latitude and longitude from consumer in the query string. use those value in your get API code. the sample code can then be written as follows

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   if(req.query.latitude && req.query.longitude){
  const latitude = req.query.latitude;
  const longitude = req.query.longitude;
  landmark
  .find(
    {
    geometry:{
        $nearSphere: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Point",
          coordinates : [longitude, latitude]
        },
        $minDistance: 0,
        $maxDistance: 500
        }}
  }
  )
  .then(landmark => {
    res.json(landmark);
  });
   }
   else{
      res.json('No parameter passed');
   }
});
```

The consumer then can use this API by calling a get request like follow
https://yourdomain.com/yourapiname?latitude=1.983478&longitude=6.9824387

Comment: I've got the latitude and longitude in the client side, and using localhost:3000 for the client side, but i don't know how to send that to the server which using localhost:5000 and use it as parameter for the get route

Answer (score 0):

First of all the express import is unnecessary I think. Assuming you are making the right request from the client it seems like you not using a body parser.

You can use the built in one from express or the one from bodyParser. An example with bodyparser below:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 
var app = express()
 
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

This can go in your server file, ex app.js. It does not have to be imported in your routes module again.

Comment: I already have express.json() in my app.js file, I'm sorry that I didn't mention that on my question

Comment: No problem! I am a little confused when your error happens. In the post or get method? Because you cannot access a variable created in another function

Comment: In this case you can replace the code from your post function with that from the get function. So when posting a coordinate the landmark is responded immediately. If you want to keep it seperated you should use a database or something. Saving data in a variable isn't a good option in your case if for example you have multiple users at the same time